# How to make a nice overlay with variable transparency using WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, transparent, alpha-transparency

I'm looking for a way to make a WinForm transparent and allow to use semi-transparent images on it.

The common solutions are:

- Changing the total opacity of the form and all of its content;
- Make only a certain color fully transparent, while the rest will have to be fully opaque;
- Use multiple forms to make only some controls transparent.

None of these ways allow to display images or controls which have variable per-pixel transparency value. And I'd like to achieve a cool interface like Steam does with its in-game overlay.

Is there maybe some video game technique that can be used to draw a nice overlay for the whole screen? It's okay if it will have to use 3D graphics drawing libraries and whatnot.

Comment: Layered windows [UpdateLayeredWindow function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Per-pixel alpha transparency is pretty easy to get going in Winforms, just follow the google hits.  Finding out that a lot of the controls in the toolbox don't work anymore is however a pretty rough discovery.  Creating your own TextBox control isn't that simple.  It has been done, it is called WPF.